# Error in Bash scripting nmap nse scan

Tags: bash, scripting, nmap

I'm in the process of getting a new job as a pen-tester and I figured it'd be useful to get more aquainted with bash. I'm having trouble with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ip in $(cat webSerVer.txt |grep "192.168.19"|cut -d" " -f5);do

nmap $ip --script smb‐os-discovery.nse > smb‐os-discovery.txt

done
```

I get the following error:

```
NSE: failed to initialize the script engine:
/usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:685: Bad script rule:
    smb‐os-discovery.nse ->  <eof> expected near char(226)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:685: in function 'get_chosen_scripts'
    /usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:1271: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?

QUITTING!
```

What am I missing to make this script run Nmap against all of the IP's? If I run `cat webSerVer.txt |grep "192.168.19"|cut -d" " -f5` - I get a list of IP's, so I know this is correct.

My nmap command seems to be the line causing issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like there may be good resources ove at U&L stack site - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139053/how-to-scan-for-heartbleed-vulnerability-with-nmap-from-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: if you've created any of the files in Windows and then moved them to Linux/Unix, use `dos2unix file1 file2 ...`. Good luck.

Comment: Hi guys, no the list of IP's is from another nmap scan and i've cut them down so I can just get the IP's. I want to run an nmap scan against the IP's in a bash loop.

Comment: so you're saying the `<eof> expected near char(226)` error message is bogus ? what is at char 226 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your bash scripting. Nmap (or rather the Lua parser embedded in Nmap) is complaining that there is a UTF8-encoded character somewhere in smb-os-discovery (or one of the libraries included therein. Lua can handle Unicode strings, but not Unicode identifiers. The `char(266)` part means a `\xe2` byte is in your file. This smells suspiciously like a copy-and-paste-from-MS-Word error, since the fancy left- and right-quotes Word uses (U+2018, U+2019, U+201C, U+201D) are all encoded as 3-byte UTF-8 sequences that begin with `\xe2`.

To fix it, use the scripts that ship with Nmap, or download them directly from nmap.org.